# C pthread_join segmentation fault

Tags: c, pthreads, posix

I am trying to write a C program that calculates the size of a directory tree using threads for my assignment.

**My code works fine when there is only one subdirectory, however whenever I have 2 or more subdirectories, I am getting a Segmentation Fault error.** I was reading a lot about it and was not able to find a reason for my code to fail.

In my **global** scope:

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
int total_size = 0; // Global, to accumulate the size
```

**main():**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t thread;

    ...

    if (pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL) < 0) 
    {
        perror("pthread_mutex_init");
        exit(1);
    }

    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, dirsize, (void*)dirpath);
    pthread_join(thread, NULL);

    printf("\nTotal size: %d\n\n", total_size);

...
}
```

My **dirsize()** function:

```
void* dirsize(void* dir)
{
    ...

    pthread_t tid[100];
    int threads_created = 0;

    dp=opendir(dir);
    chdir(dir);

    // Loop over files in directory
    while ((entry = readdir(dp)) != NULL)
    {
        ...

        // Check if directory
        if (S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode))
        {
            // Create new thread & call itself recursively
            pthread_create(&tid[threads_created], NULL, dirsize, (void*)entry->d_name);
            threads_created++;
        }
        else
        {
            // Add filesize
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            total_size += statbuf.st_size;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < threads_created; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Would greatly appreciate if you could point me to the right direction.

Here is what I'm getting through gdb: http://pastebin.com/TUkHspHH

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you should provide the full dirsize source code.

Comment: what is `entry->d_name`? Is it the same type as `dirpath`?

Comment: `entry` is a pointer returned by readdir. Sorry, ommitted that. I updated the code to reflect it.

Comment: I suggest checking the stacktrace after the segfault. You can load the coredump in gdb and type bt. If you don't have coredump, load the executable in gdb, run, and bt when you get the segfault. Then you could see exactly where the segfault occurred.

Comment: @Mellowcandle For some reason my gdb crashes: http://pastebin.com/TUkHspHH

Comment: The gbd output does not fit to the sources you show.

Comment: Always test system calls for errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's the value of **NUM_THREADS**?

```
    // Check if directory
    if (S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode))
    {
        // Create new thread & call itself recursively
        pthread_create(&tid[threads_created], NULL, dirsize, (void*)entry->d_name);
        threads_created++;
    }
```

Here you should check if **threads_created** is equal to **NUM_THREADS** and if so increase the size of the **tid** array (that I would **malloc** at the function begin and **free** at the end, btw).

Moreover you should allocate a copy of the directory name (malloc + strcpy) before you pass it as argument to the thread and free such copy at the end of the function instead of `entry->d_name`.

Comment: The value of NUM_THREADS is large enough (1000) and the directory structure I'm using is very small.

Comment: thank you, I tried that, but it still causes segfault. I will try using gdb to backtrace it. If I find out what caused the problem, I will post it here.